# Wordpress changing site url by category

Tags: wordpress, categories

First of all, I'm new to WordPress. I have an doubt for changing url of my site by city wise.

I have below pages

```
Home
About Us
Games
Locations
Contact Us
```

In Locations pages i have an google map with multiple cities locations for example: florida, california,etc...

When i click the florida location then the URL of my site should be changed into

```
www.mysite.com/florida
www.mysite.com/florida/about-us
www.mysite.com/florida/games
www.mysite.com/florida/locatins
www.mysite.com/florida/contact-us
```

Like wise for other cities also..

How could i get this feature in WordPress any ideas?

Please let me know

Comment: Try settings / perm. links if that helps you..

Comment: By modifying the .htaccess and the perm link option in the dashboard will help you to solve this.